Promethus not taking metrics from routes
const reqResTime = new client.Histogram({
  name: 'http_express_req_res_time',
  help: 'Duration of HTTP requests in milliseconds',
  labelNames: ['method', 'route', 'status_code'], 
  buckets: [0.1, 5, 15, 50, 100, 500], 
});


app.use(
  responseTime((req: Request, res: Response, time: number) => {
    let route = req.route?.path || req.originalUrl || 'unknown_route';

   
    if (route === '/favicon.ico') return;


    reqResTime.labels(req.method, route, res.statusCode.toString()).observe(time);
  })
);

I am using Prometheus as docker-compose file and trying to get data,but with each request it's not getting reflected when I check in Promethus page my config is
global:
  scrape_interval: 4s

scrape_configs:
  - job_name: prometheus
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['host.docker.internal:8080']


Your question is not a minimal repro of your issue making it difficult for us to help. host.docker.internal is a mechanism to connect from a container to the host but, your question suggests that you're running the Node.JS app and Prometheus under Docker Compose. If so, you should replace host.docker.internal with the Docker Service service name of the Node.JS app assuming that it's also running on the service's port 8080.
